# Bar chart with one dataset but multiple labels

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a graph based on data from database using Chart.js, and I'm running into issues with making multiple labels for the data. One label is the month that the data is a part of, and the second label is the type of visit.

Here's what I have at the moment.

[image]

I'm doing this by adding in another label just for this one case:

```
xAxes: [{
        position: 'top',
        offset: 1,
        ticks: {
            fontColor: 'black',
            beginAtZero: true,
            fontSize: 35,
        },
        gridLines: {
            display: false
        },
    },
        {
            labels: ["M   SP   W/I   B", "M   SP   W/I   B"],
            position: 'bottom',
            offset: 1,
            ticks: {
                fontColor: 'black',
                beginAtZero: true,
                fontSize: 35,
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            },
        }
    ]
```

Problem is it's too McGyvery. My plan is to add another Label for the dataset, besides the Month/Year and put the visit types there. This will deal with the problem where there's more or less than two months on the graph.

What I would really like to do is make it so that each bar has the label underneath it (I've already tried with the label on the bar next to the number, and it does not look good). And also I would like to get rid of the empty spaces left by the 0 value bars that would be amazing, which has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390740/hide-empty-bars-in-grouped-stacked-bar-chart-chart-js).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to get at.

[image]

Is there any way to do this with Chart.js?